# Dimensional Difference between Running mean and Sample mean in Batch normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am recently teaching my self through cs231n online, and in batch normalizetion assignment, specifically in running mean calculation: 
`running_mean = momentum * running_mean + (1 - momentum) * sample_mean`
the `running_mean` is set by
`running_mean = bn_param.get("running_mean", np.zeros(D, dtype=x.dtype))`. 
So when you have more than one batchnorm layer, the `running_mean` value is inherited from the last batchnorm layer, but the `sample_mean` is obtained by current layer input, which result in

```
File ~/assignment/assignment2/cs231n/layers.py:217, in batchnorm_forward(x, gamma, beta, bn_param)
    213 out = x_hat * gamma + beta
    215 print(running_mean.shape, miu.shape)
--> 217 running_mean = momentum * running_mean + (1 - momentum) * miu
    218 running_var = momentum * running_var + (1 - momentum) * sigma_squared
    220 cache = miu, sigma_squared, eps, N, x_hat, x, gamma

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,20) (1,30)
```

what did I miss here? The derivation seems right though

I tried to implement the batchnorm layer, but the dimension is different between running_mean and sample_mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have:

```
        miu = np.mean(x, axis=0)
        var = np.var(x, axis=0)
        x_hat = (x - miu) / np.sqrt(var + eps)
        out = x_hat * gamma + beta
        print(running_mean.shape, miu.shape)
        running_mean = momentum * running_mean + (1 - momentum) * miu
        running_var = momentum * running_var + (1 - momentum) * var
        cache = miu, var, eps, N, x_hat, x, gamma
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! It turned out that I just could not have the correct i of  bn_param[i] delievered to the batchnorm_forward, but I haven't check what actually happened with the different dimension variable in the background